# When changing the type of a .net user control property, is it possible to automatically update designer property values?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

We have a .net (VB) class library (dll) containing user controls, and several VB/C# Windows Forms Projects using many instances of those controls.  The controls were inserted and properties set with the designer.
Some of those properties are of legacy types that we've avoided updating for fear of having to edit thousands of lines of designer code.
Is there some means by which we can accomplish an automatic conversion of designer property values stored in the .designer.vb files at the first project build or designer load with a new library version?
Trivial Example:

Older version of class library has:

```
Public Class UserControl1
    Public Property choice As String
End Class
'Then the .designer.vb file has
        '
        'UserControl1
        '
        Me.UserControl1.choice = "Maybe"
        ...
```

Newer version of class library has:

```
Public Enum PossibleChoices
    A
    B
    C
End Enum
Public Class UserControl1
    Public Property choice As PossibleChoices
End Class
```

Then when we open an application built with the older version that uses UserControl1, and load a form in the designer, we get (as expected)

"Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'VB_PropertyTypeChangeTest.PossibleChoices'."

Is there some means by which we can catch/intercept that error and inject a property value conversion function into the process to avoid manually editing thousands of lines of designer code?

Ideally it would update 'Me.UserControl1.choice = "Maybe"' to 'Me.UserControl1.choice = PossibleChoices.A', allowing us to strip the conversion code from some future version, though conceivably it could leave it unchanged and continue performing the conversion on each load in perpetuity.

(Writing a stand-alone tool that parses and edits the .designer.vb files is a possibility, but I suspect it would be time consuming to manage.)

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.  Thank you,

David

Comment: VS has a search and replace utility, with Regex matches. Otherwise ReSharper has built-in [refactoring tools](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_refactoring.html) -- Not sure whether the 30-days trial has these tools available

Comment: I imagine that going through the code to make the necessary changes will take less time than the amount of time you spend trying to avoid going through it or time spent trying to find another way. No matter the approach, ensure that you've made a backup of your project before proceeding.

Comment: designer files are just text files.  If not using VS tools for find and replace, then any number of external text search tools will work.  I do agree with above comments, this is possible one of these situations where you can spend more time finding the shortcut, using the shortcut and any manual clean up than if you just did it properly in the first place.

Comment: In similar situations, I would consider creating a new library and replace the references over time if feasible